# Rows or Size of a Fact Table

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

I just had an interview and couldn't answer one question which states "How many rows can a Fact table contain?" and "What is the maximum size of a fact table?"

Comment: Those questions without context are ridicuous. The size is limited by the storage size. This page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 says "limited by available storage"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Besides the storage size limitations, if the definition of a table requires there to be a primary key, the largest numeric key possible is NUMERIC(38, 0).  It would be 17 bytes and would allow for from -10^38+1 through 10^38-1 rows.

Comment: Hello @SteveC! Even for `char` type keys, does it have this size limitation?

Comment: The PK could be a `char(800)`  or a composite key.  The number of rows per table is limited only by available storage per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=Database%20Engine%20objects%20%20%20%20SQL%20Server,a%20cluster%20...%20%206%20more%20rows%20

Comment: char(800) has about 256^800 distinct values or (2^8)^800 = 2^6400 which is about 10^1900. Even with case-insensitive a-z, 0-9, that's more than 32^800 = 2^4000 which is about 10^1200. So the key space of the table is not a relevant limitation, as it's probably more than you could store on a galaxy-sized flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

Other than limitations imposed by the database or amount of storage required, fact tables don't have a max size.